# Is there a way to make an ICS Tab Bar to become backwards compatible with Gingerbread and Froyo?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Or is there a close equivalent to making this control work pre-ICS?

I got ActionBar covered with ActionBarSherlock, but I'm not sure how to get TabBar working the same way...

Answer (score 1):

There is no `TabBar` in any version of Android.

If you mean "tabs in the action bar", ActionBarSherlock supports that.